# How do I know a pan-event has ended in nativescript-vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

The documentation of nativescript-vue provides little information on gestures. They can be used like so `<Button @pan="handler" />`, but how do I know, wether e.g. a pan event has ended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on [gestures](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/gestures) is scattered, to date. But here is [what I found](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1366#issuecomment-171323411): the event handler is passed an event object, as usual. This has a property called `state` which is a number to be interpreted using the [GestureStateTypes](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/enums/_ui_gestures_.gesturestatetypes) enum. You can determine, wether the pan-event has ended like so:

```js
import { GestureStateTypes } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/gestures';

export default {
    methods: {
        pan(event) {
            if (event.state === GestureStateTypes.ended) {
                console.log('Pan event has ended.');
            }
        },
    },
}
```

These are all possible event states: `began`, `cancelled`, `changed`, `ended`.